# Sequelize.js belongsToMany instance method create not working?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

My models:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Entity;
  return Entity = sequelize.define('Entity', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        return Entity.belongsToMany(models.User);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

and

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User;
  return User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true
      }
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM('active', 'inactive'),
      defaultValue: 'active'
    }
  }, {
    instanceMethods: {
      display: function() {
        var user;
        user = {
          name: this.name,
          email: this.email,
          username: this.username,
          active: this.active
        };
        return user;
      }
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        return User.belongsToMany(models.Entity);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

I want to create a user and then attach one entity to that user, so I am doing:

```
newUser = {
  name: req.body.name,
  email: req.body.email,
  username: req.body.username,
  password: req.body.password
};

global.db.User.create(newUser).then(function(dbUser) {
  var newEntity;
  newEntity = {
    name: newUser.name + " Default Entity"
  };
  console.log(dbUser);
  return dbUser.createEntity(newEntity);
}).then(function(dbEntity) {
  return console.log(dbEntity);
});
```

But I get an error: `[TypeError: Object [object SequelizeInstance] has no method 'createEntity']`

This is using `Sequelize` v2.0.0-rc8

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dbUser is an instance, so `dbUser.createEntity()` is calling the instance method `createEntity()` on the `dbUser` instance. Which doesn't exist.

The correct solution is to call `create` on your `Entity` model, with the `UserId` field set to `dbUser.id`. So, something like:

```
global.db.Entity.create({name: 'blah blah blah', UserId: dbUser.id})
```

(you may have to fiddle around with the capitalization).

Also, I think you may want `User.hasMany(models.Entity)`, but that's just something that caught me off guard.

Comment: but `dbUser` does exist. It was created in the line: `global.db.User.create(newUser).then(function(dbUser) {`. And the `belongsToMany` is new and supposed to handle this.

Comment: @Shamoon he is trying to tell you that dbUser does not have the method `#createEntity()`. The `createEntity()` method is injected to your Models, which would be `User`. Your 'dbUser' is a dao instance of the model which only have the `#getEntity` and `#setEntity` methods.

Comment: `createEntity` actually should exist, `:M` associations in Sequelize support `createAssociation`